# Installing OpenMP-enabled XGBoost

Tags: homebrew, python, gcc

I have scoured the web trying to figure out how to install XGboost. A simple pip or conda install does not work, even though it worked for many of my colleagues. I went to the installation guide which directed me to run the following to install gcc:

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

To confirm I already have it installed I tried again and received the following message:

```
Warning: gcc-7.1.0 already installed
```

So I should be good there.
Then I clone the repository with:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
```

and then run the following:

```
cd xgboost; cp make/config.mk ./config.mk; make -j4
```

and run in to the following errors:

> c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
>   c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
>   c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/c_api/c_api.o src/c_api/c_api.cc >build/c_api/c_api.d
>   c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/c_api/c_api_error.o src/c_api/c_api_error.cc >build/c_api/c_api_error.d
>   clangclang: : errorerror: : unsupported option '-fopenmp'unsupported option '-fopenmp'
>
> clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
>   clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
>   make: *** [build/c_api/c_api_error.o] Error 1
>   make:**  Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   make:  **[build/logging.o] Error 1
>   make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 1
>   make: *** [build/c_api/c_api.o] Error 1

I can't make sense of what the issue is, but really need XGboost to run through Python on my computer!

installation guide:
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

system version: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.4

Comment: Please add your system version and a link to the installation guide you followed, by editing your question. Don't post the details as a comment!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had the exact same error as you and here is what I did to solve it.  I edited the first few lines of the config.mk file yopu are copying to be

```
export CC = gcc-7
export CXX = g++-7
```

because you are using gcc 7.1

Then you can finish making and building as you can find in many tutorials (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315156/how-to-install-xgboost-in-python-on-macos)

Answer (score 0):

The [XGBoost Python installation instructions](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/python-package) say that you need to install `gcc@5` because OpenMP support was removed after that version.  Then just set a couple of env. vars so that your `pip install` uses this version:

```
brew install gcc@5
CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 pip install xgboost>=0.7
```